# Google Maps API and Github pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3, github-pages

So Im trying to put my resume on git pages and it contains the google map API, when I open up the file without any server it runs fine. But when I run it on my git hub page it throws me the error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jcook894.github.io/My_Resume/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script "'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'". This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

and then this error:

> helper.js:121 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
>       at initializeMap

Is there something wrong with my api key that it isnt going through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the problem with mixed content just load google maps over https:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=XXXXXX
```

For more information for GitHub Pages and Mixed content see [the documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https/#resolving-problems-with-mixed-content).

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, just realized I forgot to add s to https -_-